# Using @Multipart in retrofit to include @FormUrlEncoded as well

Tags: java, json, post, retrofit

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Endpoints.KID_PROFILE_BASE + "/{uuid}" + Endpoints.POST_KID_PROFILE_END)
void postKidProfilePhoto(@Path(value = "uuid", encode = false) String startuuid, @Part("post[body]") TypedString requestJson, Callback<KidProfile> callback);
```

I have the code above. This `POST` should format a dynamic url (which works with the FormUrlEncoded), and then fill the `Body` parameter with a `TypedString` of `Json` data.

However when I make the request to the url, `retrofit` throws the error:

```
Only one encoding annotation is allowed.
```

Which means I have to give up either `@Multipart` or `@FormUrlEncoded`. Is there a way to keep both of them in order to not throw away dynamically generating my url? Or a work around?

I know I can remove `@FormUrlEncoded` and somehow include it as a `@Part` in my `postKidProfilePhoto` but I am not sure the procedure to do that and cannot find any documentation showing that being done.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use `@FormUrlEncoded` with `@Multipart` as they say [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/662), it works without it?